# python can't use a property defined in the super (father) class

Tags: python

This is my code

```
class ElasticsearchController(object):
     def __init__(self):
         self.es = Elasticsearch(['blabla'], port=9200)

class MasterDataIndexController(ElasticsearchController):
     def __init__(self):
         self.indexName = "bbbbb"
     def search(self, query):
         return super.es.search(index=self.indexName, docuemntType = self.documentType, query = query)
```

I got this error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'super' has no attribute 'es'
```

though the super does have it.

Any idea please?

Comment: `super().es.search(...)`

Comment: you should instantiate the parent constructor. In the child's `__init__`, call `super().__init__()`. Then you can just call it via `self.es`

Comment: You're expecting a rather Java-like behavior here. `super` isn't a keyword, and you don't use it like that. Superclass constructors must be called manually; you don't implicitly get a call to the default superclass constructor if you leave it out. You never need `super` to access an instance variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not initialising your super classes.

```
class ElasticsearchController(object):
     def __init__(self):
         self.es = Elasticsearch(['a.b.c.d'], port=1234)

class MasterDataIndexController(ElasticsearchController):
     def __init__(self):
         super(MasterDataIndexController, self).__init__()
         #^^^^^^^^^^^
         self.indexName = "bbbbb"

     def search(self, query):
         return self.es.search(index=self.indexName, docuemntType = self.documentType, query = query)
         #      ^^^^^ self should be fine.
```

Comment: You don't pass `self` when using `super`.

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli I shouldn't be passing in a self. My bad. I have updated my answer.

Comment: It is working. thanks so much. will accept it when the system allows

Comment: Also, @MarcoDinatsoli indicate in your question whether you are using Python2.x or Python3.x (there are tags for each). If you are using 3.x, you can just use `super().__init__()` without the `MasterDataIndexController, self` arguments.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `super` like that. `super` will give you access to the super class, but you should not use it as a shortcut for `self`. Depending if you use python or python 3, you can call `super(MyClass, self)` or just `super()`. You can use this during initialization to call the `__init__` method of your superclass.

However, in most simple class hierarchies, it is not necessary to call super and your code will be clearer if you just called `SuperClass.__init__(self)`.

After this you should be able to just use `self` and attribute access.

Comment: self didn't work, i had tried with self before i asked

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli: That was because you didn't call the parent constructor.

Comment: Yes, as SuperSaiyan says, you need to call the initialization methods of the parents explicitly. There is very little magic in python.